# Reverse Deep Zoom Image to high-res flat image

Tags: image, zooming, deepzoom

I have a collection of .dzi images (with corresponding split-up JPEGs) on my local computer. I want to reverse these images into a flat, hi-res image.

I googled, but couldn't find any software/scripts/tools to do this.

Any help?

Thanks,
Deckwasher

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool called dezoomify https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify which automatically generates a single high-res image based on a single tile image url.
It works for most tile server formats.

Comment: Thanks, great tool !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) with:

```
vips arrayjoin "$(echo *.jpeg | sort -t_ -k2g -k1g)" x.tif --across 20
```

This will get all the `xxx_yyy.jpeg` files and sort them into row-major order (split the filename on `_`, sort by key 2 first), join into a big array 20 tiles across (you'll want to change this number) and write to `x.tif`.

It's fast and should work on images of any size.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly theoretically possible, but I don't know of any tool that does it directly. Basically you'd just want to take the highest resolution level and tile all the images back together.

You might take a look at this plugin for OpenSeadragon:

https://github.com/KTGLeiden/Openseadragon-screenshot

Set your viewer to the original image size and it should more or less do what you're looking for.